# Using wordpress post data as input for google visualisations

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to use wordpress post data (eg title, link, custom fields) as a data source for google visualisations.

I want to be able to take the wordpress data for all posts and visualise using the "table" and "motion" charts.

Related doc
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table.html

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motion.HTML

How do I loop though all my posts to create an array that that will work as a data source? I want to get post titles, post urls and associated custom fields for graphing.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just use the WordPress loop with a custom query to throw all the data you need into arrays.

For example if you want all the post titles in an array (using `get_posts`);

```
$all_posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
$all_titles = array();
 foreach( $all_posts as $all_post ) {
  $all_titles[] = $all_post->post_title;
 }
```

As for using the data in Google charts that is up to you, but I would recommend using JSON ( using `json_encode`), XML or one of the many PHP chart wrappers.